# Why _app.name error in my auth.dart flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have this code in my `auth.dart` flutter, but why _app.name error ?

```
Future<void> reload() {
    return FirebaseAuthPlatform.instance.reload(_app.name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's your ```_app```?

Comment: i already solved this problem, thanks for the respond :)